# Selectors for multiple instance of NGRX reducers

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a reducer that use for search and realized that it needs to be used for multiple un-related search components. So, looking through the Redux documentation I found the concept of higher order reducers (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html#customizing-behavior-with-higher-order-reducers) (meta reducers in ngrx) and used that to create 2 'instances' of my search reducer. I then found in the same documentation that this will appear to work with selectors but actually has an issue with the memoization (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html#accessing-react-props-in-selectors). That article references a function called 'mapStateToProps' which seems to be React specific way of connecting the store data to components (if I understand it correctly...).

Is there an equivalent in ngrx or is there another way of creating these selectors to work with the different instances of the reducers?

Below is a mildly contrived example based on the ngrx example app of what I am trying to accomplish:

**reducers/searchReducer.ts:**

```
export interface State {
  ids: string[];
  loading: boolean;
  query: string;
};

const initialState: State = {
  ids: [],
  loading: false,
  query: ''
};

export const createSearchReducer = (instanceName: string) => {
  return (state = initialState, action: actions.Actions): State => {
    const {name} = action; // Use this name to differentiate instances when dispatching an action.
    if(name !== instanceName) return state;

    switch (action.type) { 
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.ts:**

```
export interface State {
  search: fromSearch.State;
}

const reducers = {
  search: combineReducers({
    books: searchReducer.createReducer('books'),
    magazines: searchReducer.createReducer('magazines')
  }),
}


export const getSearchState = (state: State) => state.search;

// (1)
export const getSearchIds = createSelector(getSearchState, fromSearch.getIds);
```

I believe the getSearchIds selector above needs the ability somehow to specify which instance of the search Reducer it is accessing. (Strangely, in my code it **seems** to work but I am not sure how it knows which to select from and I assume it has the memoization issue discussed in the Redux documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Kevin's answer makes sense for the contrived code example I gave, there are definitely maintenance issues if each reducer 'instance' has many properties or if you need many 'instances'. In those cases you would wind up with many quasi-duplicate properties on a single reducer (ex. 'bookIds', 'magazineIds', 'dvdIds', 'microficheIds', etc.).

With that in mind, I went back to the Redux documentation and followed it to the FAQ for selectors, specifically [How Do I create a Selector That Takes an Argument](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument).

From that information, I put this together:

**reducers/index.ts:**

```
export const getBookSearchState = (state: State) => state.search;
export const getMagazineSearchState = (state: State) => state.search;

// A function to allow the developer to choose the instance of search reducer to target in their selector. 
export const chooseSearchInstance = (instance: string): ((state: State) => searchReducer.State) => {
    switch(instance) {
        case 'books': {
            return getBookSearchState;
        }
        case 'magazines': {
            return getMagazineSearchState;
        }
    }
}

// Determines the instance based on the param and returns the selector function.
export const getSearchIds = (instance: string) => {
    const searchState = chooseSearchInstance(instance);
    return createSelector(searchState, state => state.ids);
}
```

**In some component where you know the reducer you want to use:**

```
//...
class SearchComponent {
    @Input()
    searchType: string = 'books'; 
    ids: Observable<number>;

    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {    
        this.store.select(fromRoot.getSearchIds(searchType));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rethinking your way of doing this and use the same reducer and make another switch case.

Unrelated to that, the newer version of AOT doesn't like using '=>' to create your reducers. Instead use

```
export function SearchReducer (state : State = initialState, { type, payload }){
   switch (type) {
      //cases...
   }
}
```

and you won't have to use combineReducers, you can just build out your reducer object

```
let reducers = {
   search: SearchReducer
}
```

Saying your state is of the interface State type lets you take advantage of that typing.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer of making another switch case? It sounds like you mean to make duplicate properties of the State interface. But that does not sound DRY to make duplicate properties and use the same cod in different switch statements.

Comment: I think it would be better to have an extra property within a reducer rather than an extra reducer